# Trackpad Not Working

Tags: lubuntu, touchpad

Running 4.13.0-37-generic GNU/Linux on Dell Inspiron 3180. Trackpad stops working after bootup. Already tried updating the grub file.

Anyone else have issues with their trackpad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to kernel 4.15 seemed to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

trackpad working using 17.10
didn't work at first until fixed wifi then 
in terminal 
ran sudo apt-get update.
sudo apt-get upgrade
prompted to install updates from software center
then restart. Works fine.